# Prevent user to access wordpress login page

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to prevent user to access my login page:

```
global $pagenow;

if ( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow && ! in_array( ! empty( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : '', array( 'lostpassword', 'logout', ) ) )
{
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 );
    exit();
}
```

It works well and I can't access login page anymore. I also use Simple History plugin to track logs and I still see that someone tries to login my site so many times.

> Failed to login with username "*********" (username does not exist) warning

I was wondering why someone can access my login page. Am I missing something in above code?

Comment: You could also rewrite login url with a custom one. I personally use this plugin [All In One WP Security & Firewall](https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/)